# WordPress wp-load throwing database error

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line-interface

I'm writing a php script to synchronize some posts with WordPress and the script is meant to be executed via the terminal.

### sync.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../../wp-load.php';
echo 'WordPress loaded!' . PHP_EOL;
```

Now, when I execute the script:

```
php sync.php
```

I get a database connection error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Database Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load the WordPress via the browser, everything loads up fine. Therefore, my database connection credentials are valid.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Is there any reason why I would get the error when I run it via the command line?

### Update

It's not the path of `wp-load` that is invalid because if the path was wrong, or the file is not found, I would get a failed to open stream warning. For example, if I replace the `require` with the following (removed one `/../`):

```
require __DIR__ . '/../wp-load.php';
```

Then I execute the code, I get the following warning:

> PHP Warning:  require(**path**): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **path** on line 28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Webserver and CLI run with different configs

Environment variables (like `__DIR__`, connection settings (interpretations of "localhost" and application ports, and virtual-host directives and directory-root, can all vary between the two.

1. Paths and Directory-root
2. Connection settings
3. Environment Variables

### Paths and directory-root

Your paths may be are different between command-line and your webserver (apache/nginx?). Check them carefully to see what you're actually trying to load

One of these is not like the others:

- relative path `/../../wp-load.php`
- the constant `__DIR__`

**Echo [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to see what is happening**.

Run it again, both in a browser and via command-line.

```
// sync.php
<?php

echo __DIR__ . "\n";
echo realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'). "\n";
echo realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../'). "\n";
echo realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../wp-load.php'). "\n";

//require __DIR__ . '/../../wp-load.php';
//echo 'WordPress loaded!' . PHP_EOL;
```

Note: `realpath` will return *false* if the file does not exist.

### Connection Settings

Network connections and access permissions will likely vary between a Web request and a CLI call. This is due to two major factors: PHP will be running as a different user, and will likely be interpreted as connecting from a *slightly* different IP.

First and foremost, check the MySQL logs for errors. There you will likely find errors along the lines of `Access denied for root@127.0.0.1:3306`. This is caused by the user only being granted access via a specific host. See what's up by running the [MySQL: SHOW GRANTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) command.

This may even become more clear simply by [connecting to MySQL via the CLI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html): 
`# mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=root database-name`

Some testing of `[mysql_connect](http://se2.php.net/mysql_connect)` may narrow down the issue for you:

```
function testConn(string $host) {

    echo "\n\n MySql (".$host.") :\n";

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

    mysqli_close($link);

}

testConn(DB_HOST);
testConn('localhost');
testConn('127.0.0.1');
testConn('mydomain.com');
testConn('localhost:3306');
testConn('127.0.0.1:3306');
```

### Environment Variables

Other differences in config and environment variables can be fairly difficult to track down. The best place to start would be comparing the results of `phpinfo();`.

Comment: If the path was the problem, `wp-load.php` wouldn't load and I would get a different error. Have a look at my update.

Comment: @ChinLeung, so now at least we know it wasn't `__DIR__`, and I know you're not silencing errors. The next thing to check is that `localhost`, and mysql conn ports, are the same between the CLI and the Webserver. (updating answer now).

Comment: @ChinLeung, carefully check the mysql user permissions. When connecting via CLI, it's probably a different host (automatically interpreted as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost), and your user is specific to `root@localhost`, or some variation thereof.

Comment: Thanks, changing the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in `wp-config.php` fixed the issue.